# Android: How to add a Button under a Button

Tags: android, format

Right now my xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable="false"
    android:hint="@string/table"
    android:text="@string/table"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tableButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/copy"
    android:onClick="copy"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to add a button right under my already created button. I tried adding another button, but it just puts it in the same line. is it the LinearLayout? if so, how do I fix this?

EDIT: Clarifications, I want my EditBox and Button to be in one line, followed by another EditBox and Button.

Comment: did you want the EditText to be on the let of the currently placed button as well? or can they all be stacked on top of each other?

Comment: @LuckyMe I don't particularly care, I just need it under it :)

Comment: Easy, change `android:orientation="horizontal"` in the `LinearLayout` to `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Comment: @LuckyMe oh maybe I misinterpreted your question, I edited the question for clarification

Comment: Okay, are you adding the views programmatically or in XML file?

Comment: I'm still learning the ropes, so I'm doing it to the xml. :| If there's a better way to do it in code. Please direct me to the right approach

Comment: Check my reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464415/android-how-to-add-a-button-under-a-button?noredirect=1#answer-17464811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need then, and copy the entire inner LinearLayout to add more lines:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Copy from here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="@string/table"
            android:text="@string/table" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tableButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="copy"
            android:text="@string/copy" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- To herel, and paste under -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@id/table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="@string/table"
            android:text="@string/table" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/tableButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="copy"
            android:text="@string/copy" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As for doing this using code, it is only if you are not aware of how many you need in total, otherwise, do it in XML.

Comment: Yes, I also need the EditTexts, I modified the solution to the accepted answer a bit :) let me try this out.

Comment: Yup! This works too! Could you explain this a bit? How does the nested layouts work? Also, is it possible to expand the EditBox as far as it can?

Comment: Consider that this is more complex View hierarchy, than I gave as an example, and so it will take more time to layout, rendering all views and will take more memory.

Comment: @Shelby.S The first LinearLayout is to display the contained Views (in this case they are other LinearLayouts) in a Vertical manner, as in stacked on top of each other. Now the inner LinearLayouts each is to display its contained Views (in this case an EditText and a Button) in a horizontal manner. I think the EditText should be expanded to the maximum. [Side note, if you don't want to just display a text, use `TextView` instead of `EditText` and remove the `android:editable="false"`. `TextViews` just display, while `EditText` are for inputting text from the user.]

Comment: @LuckyMe I tried taking away EditText and use TextView instead, but I don't know how to retrieve the text. I use EditText editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.table); that to retrieve the text t.t  I know, I'm a total noob at this. So many tutorials to look at.

Comment: @AlexBonel Not really, I mean we are dealing with a nesting that is 2 layer deep, doesn't account for much. Relative layout is when nesting becomes on a larger order, or when the display of layout is complex. This is pretty simple.

Comment: @Shelby.S Only change it to `TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.table);` and all should be fine.

Comment: @LuckyMe So what is the problem to keep one level deep if you add another one `EditText` at the bottom of the first one?

Comment: @AlexBonel Nothing.. Except that you would have to create new ID's for every view and start tracking where all of them are and whatnot. Aside from that, nothing really. Up to the programmer.

Comment: @LuckyMe great! Changing it to TextView made it work just fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    <EditText 
       android:id="@+id/table"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:editable="false"
       android:hint="@string/table"
       android:text="@string/table"
      />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tableButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table
        android:text="@string/copy"
        android:onClick="copy"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tableButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tableButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/copy"
    android:onClick="copy"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tableButton"
    android:hint="@string/table"
    android:text="@string/table"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/secondButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tableButton"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/table2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_bottom="@id/table1"
    android:hint="@string/table"
    android:text="@string/table"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: They're both good answers t.t I wished I could accept them both.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tableButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/copy"
    android:onClick="copy"/>
```

into something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tableButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/copy"
        android:onClick="copy"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want the first button to have the same height as the editbox, then you will need to use [Tablelayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: The only problem I'm finding with this is, my button is now no longer next to my EditText box. I want my EditTextbox to be followed by a Button, and then below it, another set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="@string/table"
            android:text="@string/table" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tableButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="copy"
            android:text="@string/copy" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="copy"
        android:text="@string/copy" />
    </LinearLayout>
```